# Не добавляется HostObjectToScript (мостик между приложением и js сайта)

Tags: visual-studio, webview, visual-studio-2022, bridge

Я только начал работать с Visual Studio и искренне не понимаю что я делаю не так. Уже кучу примеров посмотрел, API почитал, вроде все так делаю, но не работает...

Вот так добавляю мостик *(это я уже психанул и стал добавлять его абсолютно везде...)*:

```
public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webView.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += 
            WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
            webView.NavigationCompleted += WebView_NavigationCompleted;
        }

        private void WebView_NavigationCompleted(object? sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var jsBridge = new JSBridge();
            webView.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded;
            webView.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("stb", jsBridge);
        }

        private void WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object? sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var jsBridge = new JSBridge();
            webView.CoreWebView2.OpenDevToolsWindow();
            webView.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("stb", jsBridge);
            webView.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded;
        }

        private void CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded(object? sender, CoreWebView2DOMContentLoadedEventArgs e)
        {
            var jsBridge = new JSBridge();
            webView.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("stb", jsBridge);
        }
```

Сам мостик:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class JSBridge
{
    public void play(String url)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("JS: play() " + url);
    }
}
```

На сайте вызываю **stb.play("blabla")** при нажатии на кнопку.
Вот **DevlTools** открывается, а мостик вставляться не хочет...
Использую в качестве браузера **WebView2**.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался....
Нужно было вызывать на странице с помощью **chrome.webview.hostObjects.stb.play("blabla");**